Do stable gravitational geons violate the final state conjecture?
I don't work in general relativity, but it's an area that I often feel curious about. I learned about geons from an answer by John Rennie. Despite the etymology of the term geon (gravitational electromagnetic entity), there exist vacuum = purely gravitational geons without any electromagnetic field necessary. These would effectively be vacuum solutions corresponding to gravitational waves kept together by their own gravity.
I have also heard about the final state conjecture, which I will quote from Arick Shao's A brief introduction to mathematical relativity

[T]he final state conjecture states that a generic solution of the Einstein-vacuum equations arising from asymptotically flat, or Euclidean, initial data should, asymptotically in
time, resolve into a superposition of Kerr black holes (the “solitons”) and a “radiative” part.

That is, it's expected that at late times, generic solutions to the vacuum equations are effectively far-away black holes plus gravitational waves dispersing to infinity.

My understanding of both geons and the final state conjecture is not very rigorous. Would a stable geon solution give a counterexample to the final state conjecture?

By stable, I mean heuristically in two senses: the geon survives for arbitrarily late times (with time appropriately measured), and arbitrary small perturbations to the geon metric at some fixed time/on some Cauchy surface will have the metric evolve into one that is also a stable geon in the first sense.
